# How to sum sales for a set month Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet where im tracking sales, I would like to have an overview of sales each month in another sheet so I can graph it.

my raw dater is below

```
17/06/2015  4
22/06/2015  8
35/06/2015  6
10/07/2015  2
16/07/2015  7
23/07/2015  9
24/07/2015  5
28/07/2015  1
03/08/2015  3
04/08/2015  5
06/08/2015  7
06/08/2015  4
06/08/2015  6
12/08/2015  4
```

In another sheet id like to see

```
June = 18
July = 24
August = 29
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your raw data contains invalid dates. Not sure if that is what you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the month as a numer from each day:

- 17/06/2015 ==> 06
- 22/06/2015 ==> 06
- 10/07/2015 ==> 07
- 03/08/2015 ==> 08
- 06/08/2015 ==> 08

...

Then you can use **sum.if** function.

eg:

- month number in column C
- sold item in column D

The functions for June becames:

```
=sum.if(C:C;"=06";D:D)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `June`:

```
  =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(2015,6,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2015,7,1))
```

For `July`:

```
  =SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(2015,7,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2015,8,1))
```

The sintaxis is:

```
SUMIFS(Range to sum, Criteria1 Range, Criteria1, [Criteria2 Range], [Criteria2], [Criteria3 Range], [Criteria3] )
```

More details on [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)